# how to display the response of one PHP page on the same page

Tags: php, jquery, html

Suppose I have a login form with two input fields, i.e. email address & password. When user clicks the submit button, if the response is negative, either account doesn't exist or password is incorrect (suppose i have another php file for this authentication), i wish there will be an error message displaying just under the form (the same login page). How can I achieve this ?

PS. I've searched a little bit online, it seems it's possible to accomplish this type of task with a hidden part, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262529/search-mysql-with-php-and-display-results-on-the-same-page) goes. So please suggest some better methods if possible.

PS2. I think this could be done with ajax (possibly better with JQuery). if so, a simple elegant example will be much appreciated.

**RESULT** finally, i found a nice post explaining how to achieve what I expect with JQuery, you may find this [link](http://www.jensbits.com/2009/10/04/jquery-ajax-and-jquery-post-form-submit-examples-with-php/) helpful.

Comment: The way to go here is to use AJAX.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: @Brad so could you please give me a concrete example ?

Comment: @ExplosionPills This is exactly a specific question when I encountered. Although I didn't show any code here, I think the question has been detailedly explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/ajax.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            timeout: 1000,
            error: function () {
                notifyLoadFail();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                notifyLoadFinish(data);
            }
        });

        function notifyLoadFail(){
            $('form[0]').next().append('<h2>Fail. All your base are belong to us.</h2>');
        }
```

More info here.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: This requires jQuery.  The question has no mention of jQuery.

Comment: yep, this is exactly what i want. But could you please tell me, how can I send some data in one form with this **.ajax** function ?

Comment: You would have to get the form data you want via a button onclick or something of that nature and then use that event to grab the input or value from a target area.  Finally, you would pass that value to your ajax function.  I like to wrap ajax functions in something like getJSON(url, data);  so you can re-use it.

Comment: If your form only had one element such as <input id="myInput"/>, your onclick event would grab just that input value like so: var value = $('#myInput').val();  Then pass that to your ajax wrapper.   Check out this MVC pattern tutorial for more good examples of how to re-use ajax functions.  https://github.com/adjavaherian/wulf_mvc

Answer (score 1):

you can do validation as well as displaying errors in one php-file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // form has been sent

    // do validation here, for example...
    if (!isset($_POST['user']) || strlen(trim($_POST['user'])) == 0)
        $error[] = "Please enter your username!";

    if (!isset($error)) { // no error => proceed

        // do something
    }
}
?>
<!-- next line will display $error if it is set -->
<?php=(isset($error)?'There were errors: ' . implode(',',$error):'')?>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```